# Create Ubuntu 22.04 template with packer.io ignores auto install kernel parameter

Tags: boot, system-installation, 22.04

We're using packer.io to create automated Ubuntu templates. This worked fine for Ubuntu 20.04, but I have trouble to get it to work with 22.04. Everything works fine, but when booting I get the message

```
Confirmation required to continue
Add 'autoinstall' to your kernel command to avoid this
Continue with auto install? (yes|no)
```

When typing yes, everything works as expected. This are the related lines in the packer.io config:

```
"cd_files": ["./cust//http/user-data", "./cust/http/meta-data"],
  "cd_label": "cidata",
  "boot_wait": "2s",
  "boot_command": [
    "<enter><wait2><enter><wait><f6><esc><wait>",
    " autoinstall<wait2> ds=nocloud;",
    "<wait><enter>"
  ]
```

So, as you can see, the autoinstall parameter is there (and works exactly like this in 20.04.). Anybody got in idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not been able to see how the boot_command your example, and others i found online actually could get to editing the kernel parameters.

I got around it using this so that the default boot command has the autoinstall parameter added to it on the linux line:

```
boot_command = [
    "e<down><down><down><end>",
    " autoinstall ds=nocloud;",
    "<F10>",
  ]
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you it works!